# How to merge excel files to one in Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have 9 excel files named "1_mock" to "10_mock" (It needs to skip "5_mock").
These files just have a single sheet.

Then, I want to combine those 9 files into 9 single sheets, but not to concat them into one sheet.
I've found this online merger https://products.aspose.app/cells/merger. Though it's convenient to use, I need to stop processing the code and turn to this link every time. Not very efficient at all! Thus, I hope there are ways to write this process into a code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to read all the files first and then write them to the same output file using the `to_excel` function but have a different sheet_name parameter every time. You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
files_list = ["1_mock.xlsx", "2_mock.xlsx", "3_mock.xlsx", .....]
df_list = [pd.read_excel(file_name) for file_name in files_list]
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
     for i in range(len(files_list)):
          df_list[i].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=files_list[i].replace(".xlsx",""))
```

Comment: Oh, many thanks! BTW, Is it possible to write the files_list to a loop or something else? Or it would be a little bit troublesome if there's 40 xlsx files or more

Comment: Yes, this is just an example with files_list, you can use it to your convenience